# DateTimeFormatter class exeception DateTimeParseException

Tags: android, java-8, java-time, android-date, android-dateutils

I want to get next 3 months date from the enter date in android device.
for versions greater than oreo I tried to use DateTimeFormatter. 
but I got this error "java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '28/5/2020' could not be parsed at index 0"

This is my enter date string = 28/5/2020

```
   String datestring = edittext_enterServiceDate.getText().toString();
                String dd = datestring.substring(0, 2);
                String mm = datestring.substring(3, 4);
                String yyyy = datestring.substring(5, 9);
                String dateString = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy);

                DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                LocalDate  d1 = LocalDate.parse(dateString, df);

                LocalDate returnvalue
                        = d1.plusMonths(Integer.parseInt(monthList.get(position).getStateId()));
                edittext_nextServiceDate.setText(String.valueOf(returnvalue.toString()));
```

Comment: `MM` consider as `00` of month value so you have `28/5/2020` error in month value `5` it should be `05`

Comment: It should be 28/05/2020 because your format is `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Number: If the count of letters is one, then the value is output using
>   the minimum number of digits and without padding.

Use format `dd/M/yyyy` for your date string. It will parse date Strings like `28/5/2020` and `28/12/2020` both.

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/M/yyyy");
LocalDate  d1 = LocalDate.parse("28/5/2020", df);
LocalDate  d2 = LocalDate.parse("28/07/2020", df);
LocalDate  d3 = LocalDate.parse("28/12/2020", df);
```

Comment: Or now we’re at it, `d/M/y` will give us the same flexibility in the number of digits in day of month and in year. Good answer in any case.